# LyX: PDF export reports that an auto generated temp tex file was not closed properly?

Tags: pdftex, lyx, export

For some strange reason, after editing the file in LyX, It refuses now to compile it into PDF with this little informative message.

I cleaned temp directory, restarted LyX, same thing. Strangely it dose export to say HTML, even so it says that some characters are bad... but even after removing that paragraph, and HTML export works with no errors, PDF export still gives same error, so I think it is not about wrong characters...

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a lot of try and error, I finally found the issue, it is actually a non-English character that caused this, however it was hidden in a tricky place: a URL link I put in Bibliography section!

So it seems that this ambiguous error raises indeed when you have non standard or supported characters in your text, still not sure why TeX2HTML plays fine with it, while PDFLaTeX do not.

To find it, try to copy/paste parts of your text into a new LyX file and compile it to pdf, in this way I isolated the source of my issue.

Comment: Had a similar issue, found out that the problem was a long dash *in the text after citation*, it worked when I changed to [3, Eq. (1.1)--(1.3)]